Unable to Access Partitions After Reinstalling Ubuntu 24.04 LTS - Need Help!
When I first upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, my system got stuck on the terminal login screen. Frustrated, I decided to format my Ubuntu partition and reinstall it. After the fresh installation, I was unable to access my other partitions in Ubuntu as I could previously. I received an error message saying, "Unable to access."
I tried restarting my laptop, but the issue persisted. However, I could access those partitions in Windows (I am using a dual-boot setup). I tried several times to access the partitions in Ubuntu, but it was not working. I ended up staying awake the whole night, backing up my drives, and then formatting and reinstalling both Windows and Ubuntu. After this, I was able to access the partitions, but when I tried to access my portable hard disk, I got the same error again.
I can't keep formatting my drives every time this happens. I really need a solution! I have shared a screenshot of the error I encountered: Error Screenshot.
I am a big fan of Ubuntu and would like to stick with it instead of using Windows. Can someone please help me resolve this issue? Also, I would appreciate any suggestions on how to start learning more about Ubuntu.
Thank you!
